# How to say よろしくお願いします in English?

Tags: grammar

How to say よろしくお願いします in English?

Is there a translation for the above from Japanese to English?

Is nice to meet you sufficient in this case?

Comment: it's more like "much obliged "

Comment: As sjiveru said, there are many different situations in which one might use the phrase よろしくお願いします. Is there a particular situation that you are thinking about?

Answer (score 4):

Is there a translation? No, there is not.

The meaning of よろしくお願いします corresponds to a concept English-speaking culture doesn't have, namely, the expression of goodwill before a relationship or communal activity begins. English speakers have phrases that are used in a subset of these circumstances, such as 'nice to meet you', but in other situations either nothing is said or there is no one set phrase that could be given as a translation. You'll have to translate it differently on a case-by-case basis, and sometimes the best translation to English might be not saying anything at all.

Compare 頂きます before a meal - there is no English equivalent, because English speakers simply don't say a set phrase before a meal. Maybe they say a prayer, maybe they don't say anything, but there is no phrase that corresponds even generally with 頂きます.

Comment: I think 頂きます is closest to a prayer due to the Shinto influence in its use. Kind of like "I humbly accept the spirit of this meal", or something of that nature.