# What does これからもよろしくね mean?

Tags: grammar, conversations

A Japanese person said that to me and I was utterly lost. I tried to dissect the sentence:

これ = this 
から =  from 
も = also 
よろしく = (Honestly, I don't know what this means) 
ね = a suffix that women use

I think this might mean "Nice to meet you, too." But I would like to know a more accurate explanation from someone with actual knowledge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to say よろしくお願いします in English?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/37182/how-to-say-%e3%82%88%e3%82%8d%e3%81%97%e3%81%8f%e3%81%8a%e9%a1%98%e3%81%84%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-in-english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これ = this
から = from
これから = from this point onward
よろしく comes from よろしい　＝　good, acceptance
よろしく in this case is the shortened form of よろしくおねがいします
おねがいします being the polite/formal way of saying ください = please
ね = expectation of agreement, understanding, acceptance.

これからもよろしくね = From this point forward I hope we can get along well.

or more naturally:
 - Looking forward to working with you.
 - It was good to meet you (and I expect that we will continue to have a good working relationship in the future).
 - @mamster is right, depending on context there are a plethora of innocuous business related expressions of cooperation that would fit a given situation.

Comment: `これからもよろしくね = From this point forward I hope we can get along well.` -- その「も」を訳出するのって無理なん？

Comment: hmm. I suppose the「も」 would be referencing the fact that the speaker is acknowledging that things went well today, and they hope for the same in the future too.  It's almost as if there is an unspoken 「今日も」that should come at the beginning:  今日もこれからもよろしくね or something like that. So it feels like trying to include the 「も」would just "clutter" the translation.  Hmm.  "Today went well, looking forward to working with you in the future, **too**." ...it doesn't really sound fluid and natural.

Comment: `「今日も」` -- 普通は「今までありがとう。これからもよろしくね。」って感じで使うんですけどね・・

Comment: hmm, which would be more like "Thanks for everything you've done for me up to now, and I look forward to working with you/to your support from this point on, as well."  ...It's quite a mouthful. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This whole utterance is basically a set phrase.

これから is a compound word meaning "after this" for "from now on."

Are you familiar with the phrase よろしくおねがいします? It has a variety of meanings, including "I look forward to working with you" and "thanks in advance," but also more generally just, "Great to meet you, looking forward to seeing you again." In casual speech, you can shorten it to just よろしく.

ね is not by a long shot exclusively used in feminine speech. It's a *discourse marker* that means approximately "We're on the same page about what I'm saying, right?"

So all together:

> これからもよろしくね。

Could be translated to, depending on the context, "Thanks for your continued support," "Glad we'll be working together," "Let's stay in touch." It has a professional but friendly tone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So men also use ね?

Comment: yes, men also use "ne" ... it's not gender specific. It's just a word that implies that they expect you to understand and agree with whatever sentiment or fact they've just stated. Similar to the way English speakers use the word "Okay?" or "Right?"